# is it possible to update an existing row in DB, using liquibase?

Tags: oracle, database, liquibase

Tried to find an answer to this question, but couldn't.

So, for example I have this table:

**TABLE:**

```
col1 | col2
123       0
124       1
```

and I want to change col2 value to 1 and this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
<changeSet author="myName" id="7799">
        <sql>
        UPDATE TABLENAME;
        SET COL1='1' WHERE col1='123';
        </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Alas, it doesn't work. So, I was wondering if it is even possible to do that with liquibase? Since, most tags in the documentation have to do with creating table, adding columns etc.

Comment: The `;` after `tablename` is wrong. The `;` terminates a **statement** not a single line. And the next time please include the error message. "*doesn't work*" is not helpful at all (unless the error is *that* obvious)

Comment: Hello, thank you for a reply. I tried with ; and without ; -> same result. Now, I wish I had an error message - because then I would at least know what is going wrong, but the application executes without any errors, warnings or exceptions. Just the change I want to take place in the database, doesn't.

Comment: You certain the changeset has been executed against your database? For example if you run the "changelogSync" command this would mark the changesets as executed in your database without actually running the SQL statements. Subsequently running liquibase would not execute a changeset that is marked as previously run.

Comment: You should definitively add more info to your question. Basically this is the way to go with liquibase if you want to manipulate data. And it does work. Hard to imagine that liquibase executes alright but does not produce any error. Add the command line (or what ever you use) to run liquibase. Add the output of what liquibase returns (even if it does not contain errors).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the following liquibase syntax to update:

```
<changeSet author="myname" id="7799">
    <update catalogName="dbname"
            schemaName="public"
            tableName="TABLENAME">
        <column name="COL1" value='1' type="varchar(50)"/>
        <where>col1='123'</where>
    </update>
</changeSet>
```

For the other options available please check [Liquibase Update](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html)

Comment: HEllo I don't see any `<whereClause>` tag in the documentation but rather `<where>`. I don't see the equivalence to the `SET COLUMN=Columnnewvalue` , all I see where is `UPDATE TABLENAME where col1='123'` . Correct me If am wrong. thanks